# Как заставить telegram бота на telebot реагировать на сообщение после /test command?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Например используя официальную документацию я попробовал сделать это так:

```
from telebot.types import ReactionTypeEmoji
import telebot

api = "token"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(api)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def handle_test_command(message):

reaction = ReactionTypeEmoji(type='emoji', emoji='')


bot.send_reaction(message.chat.id, message.message_id, reaction)


bot.polling()
```

Но выходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/U7283837he/test.py", line 16, in <module>
bot.polling()
File "/home/U7283837he/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/init.py", line 1104, in polling
self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
File "/home/U7283837he/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/init.py", line 1179, in __threaded_polling
raise e
File "/home/U7283837he/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/init.py", line 1141, in threaded_polling
self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
File "/home/U7283837he/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 149, in raise_exceptions
raise self.exception_info
File "/home/U7283837he/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 92, in run
task(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/U7283837he/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init.py", line 7860, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
result = handler['function'](message)
File "/home/U7283837he/test.py", line 13, in handle_test_command
bot.send_reaction(message.chat.id, message.message_id, reaction)
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'send_reaction'
```

При этом если смотреть в документацию это можно сделать (pyTelegramBotAPI 4.15.4) это описанно здесь: https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#telebot.types.ReactionTypeEmoji

Можете помочь доработать мой код чтобы бот мог ставить реакцию на сообщение?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я реализовал это так ...

```
import telebot
from random import choice
import requests

TOKEN = "TOKEN"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def text(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    message_id = message.message_id

    if 'привет' in message.text.lower():
        send_react(chat_id, message_id) # Обращение к функции send_react()

def send_react(chat_id, message_id):
    emo = ["", "", ""]
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/setMessageReaction'
    data = {
        'chat_id': chat_id,
        'message_id': message_id,
        'reaction': [
            {
                'type': 'emoji',
                #'emoji': '' # Обычный вариант с одним смайлом.
                'emoji': choice(emo) # Вариант со списком из смайликов.
            }
        ],
        'is_big': False
    }
    response = requests.post(url, json=data)
    result = response.json()

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

или 'reaction' в одну строчку ...

```
'reaction': [{'type': 'emoji', 'emoji': choice(emo)}],
```

Все реакции в документации ... https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#reactiontypeemoji